# Generating via inverse transform problem.

Tags: probability

Suppose we wish to generate $X \sim Binomial(2, \dfrac{1}{2})$ via inverse transform: $X = H(U)$ where $U \sim Uniform (0, 1)$. What is $H(y)$? ($H(y) = min\{x:y\leq F(x)\}$).

How can I do the discrete case? I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X\sim\mathrm{bin}(2,\tfrac12)$ you should be able to derive $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$. Knowing these probabilities you can write up a formula for the CDF of the form:

$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
a,\quad &x<0,\\
b,&0\leq x<1,\\
c,&1\leq x<2,\\
d,& x\geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$
for suitable $a<b<c<d$.

To find $H(y)=\min\{x: y\leq F(x)\}$ you go through it case-by-case. For instance, if $a\leq x\leq b$ then $\{x: y\leq F(x)\}=[1,\infty)$ and hence $H(y)=1$.